# Combine Infopath forms in a Document Library and make one PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, infopath2010

I want to combine infopath forms in a document library which are not based on a same template. I checked the outofthe box Merge Functionality but it combines forms in a strange way means all the repeating sections from all forms together and all the repeating tables together and that is not what I want. I just want to attach one infopath form at the end of the first and so on. Means a big file will contain all these Infopath forms one after other. After I achieve this I want to convert it to PDF.

Any good direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is possible because the xml would be invalid (having 2 nodes with the same name is not possible in InfoPath).

As for the converting to PDF, check out my [IP2HTML](http://ip2html.codeplex.com/) project (you will need a 3rd party component to convert html to pdf though). You could use the code to build your own console app or custom action that sits within the ribbon, and when executed/clicked it will iterate all items, gets the xml data from the forms and merges it with the xslt stylesheet (you manually need to extract it from the .xsn file) into a html string. Then you could use a StringBuilder to append all forms into a big one and convert it to pdf.

Comment: what about Attachment ? Does your project create HTML for attachment in the Infopath forms as well ?

Comment: What do you mean with attachements? Creating html of the actual files?  It converts the actual form (what you see in the client/browser) to HTML nothing more.. however, you can convert any XML to HTML as long as you have the matching XSLT stylesheet